# In camel route making curl with grep using exec component but grep with ${HOSTNAME} not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

In camel route I am making curl with grep using exec component but grep with ${HOSTNAME} not working,below is my camel route.Please need help on this.

```
@Component
public class VideoFilesOperationRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Value("${scheduler.cronExpression}")
    private String cron;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("quartz2://videoFilesOperations/everydayMidnight?cron=" + cron)
                .to("exec:curl?args= --silent http://localhost:4040/ | grep ${HOSTNAME}&useStderrOnEmptyStdout=true")
                .to("bean:videoFilesOperationImpl?method=videoFilesOperation");

    }
}
```

Tried Below solution but still the same issue:

```
//Tried this first
List<String> args = new ArrayList<>();
args.add("-c");
args.add("curl --silent http://localhost:4040/ | grep ${HOSTNAME}");
from("quartz2://videoFilesOperations/everydayMidnight?cron=" + cron)
.setHeader(ExecBinding.EXEC_COMMAND_ARGS, constant(args))
.to("exec:/bin/sh")
.to("bean:videoFilesOperationImpl?method=videoFilesOperation");


//Tried this next
from("quartz2://videoFilesOperations/everydayMidnight?cron=" + cron)
.to("exec:scripts/curl.sh")
.to("bean:videoFilesOperationImpl?method=videoFilesOperation");
```

Comment: "not working" is not very descriptive, do you get an error, have you verified that HOSTNAME is set, ...? Try to explain your issue a little better

Comment: This route is running in kubernetes cluster,basically Hostname its pod name where the container is running.
Yes Hostname is set.When i do grep on hostname  I guess its not applying and also its not throwing any error.

Comment: 1)exec:curl?args= --silent http://localhost:4040/
2)exec:curl?args= --silent http://localhost:4040/ | grep ${HOSTNAME}&useStderrOnEmptyStdout=true
above both are returning same result, actually in second case it should apply grep but its not happening

Comment: I don't understand your last comment but have you tried to execute your curl/grep manually ?

Comment: Yes i tried manually its working fine,below command which i tried inside pod:
curl --silent http://localhost:4040/ | grep $HOSTNAME

Comment: I mean to say,
First scenario without grep: I tried only with 'exec:curl?args= --silent http://localhost:4040/' 


Second scenario with grep :I tried with 'exec:curl?args= --silent http://localhost:4040/ | grep ${HOSTNAME}'


Both first and second scenario returning same result in camel route but when i tried manually in pod returning different result because its applying grep in second scenario but not in camel route


Hope this will clarifies you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the camel-exec command arguments are whitespace delimited. So your attempt to pipe the output from curl to grep wont work.

Try something like this:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    List<String> args = new ArrayList<>();
    args.add("-c");
    args.add("curl --silent http://localhost:4040/ | grep ${HOSTNAME}");

    from("quartz2://videoFilesOperations/everydayMidnight?cron=" + cron)
        .setHeader(ExecBinding.EXEC_COMMAND_ARGS, constant(args))
        .to("exec:/bin/sh");
}
```

Or you could just wrap the curl & grep command in a shell script and have camel-exec invoke that.

Comment: I tried above solution and curl&grep in one shell script but still the same issue :(

Comment: I have edited the question which I tried based on your suggestion but still the same issue